# Angular 1.3.0 ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with angularjs 1.3.0. I know it is not a stable version. Here is the link to the Plunker: [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WpUkLJSVFCSEAi3krjB7?p=preview).
Basically if you look at this portion of the html:

```
<p data-ng-if="myForm.handle.$pending">
   Pending request ...
</p>
```

it has a ng-if directive. So the problem appears with the ngAnimate (watch the console) it can not resolve the promise. If you change ng-if to ng-show it works fine. In order to recreate the problem start typing into the input and watch the console. 
The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Object.fn (http://run.plnkr.co/FWPMsCs7D1fTDzih/angularjs1.3.0.js:219:128)
at k.$digest (http://run.plnkr.co/FWPMsCs7D1fTDzih/angularjs1.3.0.js:118:149)
at k.$apply (http://run.plnkr.co/FWPMsCs7D1fTDzih/angularjs1.3.0.js:121:157)
at l (http://run.plnkr.co/FWPMsCs7D1fTDzih/angularjs1.3.0.js:77:491)
at u (http://run.plnkr.co/FWPMsCs7D1fTDzih/angularjs1.3.0.js:82:276)
at XMLHttpRequest.E.onreadystatechange (http://run.plnkr.co/FWPMsCs7D1fTDzih/angularjs1.3.0.js:83:343)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using angular.js 1.3.x, but your angular-animate.js is in version 1.2.x, update them to the same version should solve your problem. Replace your plunk's `<script>` tags with the following:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was the problem in my case. sometimes, the simplest problems are the most time-consuming ones.